# bootstrap-wysiwyg editor not shown

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-wysiwyg

Here's the link: http://mindmup.github.io/bootstrap-wysiwyg/. I can't get it to work. I've included the script like that:

```
<script src="js/bootstrap-wysiwyg.js"></script>
```

And done like this:

```
    <div id="alerts"></div>
<div class="btn-toolbar" data-role="editor-toolbar" data-target="#editor">
  <div class="btn-group">
    <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" title="Font"><i class="icon-font"></i><b class="caret"></b></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      </ul>
    </div>
  <div class="btn-group">
    <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" title="Font Size"><i class="icon-text-height"></i>&nbsp;<b class="caret"></b></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a data-edit="fontSize 5"><font size="5">Huge</font></a></li>
      <li><a data-edit="fontSize 3"><font size="3">Normal</font></a></li>
      <li><a data-edit="fontSize 1"><font size="1">Small</font></a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group">
    <a class="btn" data-edit="bold" title="Bold (Ctrl/Cmd+B)"><i class="icon-bold"></i></a>
    <a class="btn" data-edit="italic" title="Italic (Ctrl/Cmd+I)"><i class="icon-italic"></i></a>
    <a class="btn" data-edit="strikethrough" title="Strikethrough"><i class="icon-strikethrough"></i></a>
    <a class="btn" data-edit="underline" title="Underline (Ctrl/Cmd+U)"><i class="icon-underline"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group">
    <a class="btn" data-edit="insertunorderedlist" title="Bullet list"><i class="icon-list-ul"></i></a>
    <a class="btn" data-edit="insertorderedlist" title="Number list"><i class="icon-list-ol"></i></a>
    <a class="btn" data-edit="outdent" title="Reduce indent (Shift+Tab)"><i class="icon-indent-left"></i></a>
    <a class="btn" data-edit="indent" title="Indent (Tab)"><i class="icon-indent-right"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group">
    <a class="btn" data-edit="justifyleft" title="Align Left (Ctrl/Cmd+L)"><i class="icon-align-left"></i></a>
    <a class="btn" data-edit="justifycenter" title="Center (Ctrl/Cmd+E)"><i class="icon-align-center"></i></a>
    <a class="btn" data-edit="justifyright" title="Align Right (Ctrl/Cmd+R)"><i class="icon-align-right"></i></a>
    <a class="btn" data-edit="justifyfull" title="Justify (Ctrl/Cmd+J)"><i class="icon-align-justify"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group">
      <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" title="Hyperlink"><i class="icon-link"></i></a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu input-append">
            <input class="span2" placeholder="URL" type="text" data-edit="createLink"/>
            <button class="btn" type="button">Add</button>
    </div>
    <a class="btn" data-edit="unlink" title="Remove Hyperlink"><i class="icon-cut"></i></a>

  </div>

  <div class="btn-group">
    <a class="btn" title="Insert picture (or just drag & drop)" id="pictureBtn"><i class="icon-picture"></i></a>
    <input type="file" data-role="magic-overlay" data-target="#pictureBtn" data-edit="insertImage" />
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group">
    <a class="btn" data-edit="undo" title="Undo (Ctrl/Cmd+Z)"><i class="icon-undo"></i></a>
    <a class="btn" data-edit="redo" title="Redo (Ctrl/Cmd+Y)"><i class="icon-repeat"></i></a>
  </div>
  <input type="text" data-edit="inserttext" id="voiceBtn" x-webkit-speech="">
</div>

<div id="editor">
  Go ahead&hellip;
</div>
```

And it still doesn't show the editor. It shows the buttons and that things, but the editor isn't shown. I'm really now to using JavaScript and those things, if anyone could explain it a bit deeply, I would be grateful.

Also, on Chrome developer tools console, I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined bootstrap-wysiwyg.js:17
```

here's line 17:

```
$.fn.cleanHtml = function () {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the bootstrap library also, which also requires the jQuery library, add those both in head tags of your html. (first jQuery, then boostrap.js, then wsiwyg).

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://mindmup.s3.amazonaws.com/lib/jquery.hotkeys.js"></script>
 <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/google-code-prettify/prettify.js"></script>
```

Comment: included all of these, still here's how it looks:

http://2.imgland.net/Qn63gz.png

Comment: what does the developer console say? are there any resources that are unsuccessfully loaded under the network tab?

Comment: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/js/google-code-prettify/prettify.js`

probably because that github page is not used anymore, as of Bootstrap 3 RC 1 release.

Comment: get it from somehwere else then :)?

Comment: still, there are no errors in console but it's the same. I've just read in Usage it says I should put this somewhere: `$('#editor').wysiwyg();`. I'm not really experienced with this, so..

Comment: look at the source code of the github page and start comparing css and js, you are probably missing some css file (<link>).

Answer (score 0):

You should include also `index.css` in the head section of your HTML file. Like so:

```
<link href="path_to_your_css_files/index.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

You can copy its content from [here](https://github.com/mindmup/bootstrap-wysiwyg/blob/master/index.css)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but hopefully it may help someone coming upon it years later like myself with other issues.

Anyway, I was encountering the same problems, and here's what I did:

1. The *Cannot read property 'fn'* was due to the browser being unable to
   locate the jquery script, as I had it referenced in a block at the
   bottom of my base.html file vs the `<head>`. *I'm certain there's an
   optimal way to handle your scripts across templates without placing
   them in the `<head>` of the base.html and incurring a performance hit,
   but i'm just starting out so I'm not sure what that may be.*
2. Regarding what to do with `$('#editor').wysiwyg();` - you place this
   in a script tag at the bottom of the html file that houses your
   "#editor" div.
3. The reason its just a "box" is that they lightly touch on needing to
   add a toolbar, but don't provide the entire code for it.  However,
   you can harvest it from the demo page if you inspect it. As of this
   post it should start with something like the following:

`<div class="btn-toolbar" data-role="editor-toolbar" data-target="#editor"> 
 ...
 </div>`